# please help me to loop model and get data from rest api

Tags: json, rest, loops, model, gson

I try to loop my model in rest api
for get the object (harga)

```
 List<RingkasanOrderModel>ringkasanOrderModelList;
            Gson g;
            g = new Gson();

 ringkasanOrderModelList = g.fromJson(new String(responseBody),new 
 TypeToken<List<RingkasanOrderModel>>(){}.getType());
 for (RingkasanOrderModel ringkasanOrderModel in ringksanOrderModelList ){
                double harga = ringkasanOrderModel.harga;
                total += harga;
                ppn = harga * 0.1;
               grandtotal = total + ppn;
            }
```

Comment: Would you define more specific what problem are you facing?